# Security error accessing url in MXML

Tags: php, apache-flex, mxml

I am calling http service from flex ...

```
<mx:HTTPService id="personRequest" url="http://111.111.1.11/idesk/user.php/userinfo" useProxy="false" resultFormat="text" result="personJSON(event)" fault="anotherMethod(event)" method="post">
<mx:request xmlns="">
   <getPerson>"true"</getPerson>
</mx:request>
</mx:HTTPService>
```

and getting following error:

```
Security error accessing url
```

I have placed cross-domain policy file in server-script folder but it didnt solve my problem.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to see of what flash trying to load. It will show if swf accessed crossdomain.xml from your server and correct path.

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading from your file system? If so, you must be able to see in your address bar something like "file:// ..."
If that is the case, the Flash Player will not allow you to connect to servers (even though you have configured  your cross-domain.xml)

You have two possible solutions to solve this problem:

1. Host your Flex Application in a web server (your address will look like http:[something])
2. Add the -use-network=false in your Flex compiler arguments.

You can find more information about Flex Compiler arguments [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html)

I hope this helps.